# How to find the ID of the selected submit button

Tags: database, go, web

I have a page that is dynamically generated from my database. It basically reflects all the contents of a table.

```
 {{range .EquipmentList}}

<form method="POST" action="/cart">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1"></div>
  <div class="col-5">
     <p name="test"> {{.Name}} </p>
     <br>
     {{.Description}}
     <br>
     <button id="{{.Name}}" type="submit" class="btn btn-main btn-margin" ><b>Ausleihen</b></button> 
     {{if .Availability}}
      <input type="number" class="form-control main-input2 feld2" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="Anzahl">
     <em class="status-text" style="color:green"> verfügbar </em>
     {{else}}
      <input type="number" class="form-control main-input2 feld2" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="Anzahl">
     <em class="status-text"> entliehen </em>
     {{end}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-2"></div>
  <div class="col-2" style="margin-top: 30px">
     <img class="float-right img-responsive bild" src="{{.ImgPath}}" alt="Kann nicht gezeigt werden">
  </div>
  </div>

<div class="placeholder" style="height:50px"></div>

</form>
{{end}}
```

In the template, all devices from the DB are listed and provided with their own Submit button.

How can I find the fitting .Name entry to the triggered submit button?

I want to pass this value to my / cart located in the controller.

```
    func Cart(w http.ResponseWriter,    r   *http.Request)  {   

data := Data{ 
    Name: "Cart",
    Pages: []Page{
        {
            Title: "Meine Geräte", 
            Active: false,
            Link: "/my-equipment",
        },
        {
            Title: "Equipment", 
            Active: false,
            Link: "/equipment",
        },
        {
            Title: "Logout",
            Active: false,
            Link: "/logout",
        },
    },
}

if r.Method=="POST"{
 // SAVE .Name here
    tmpl:= template.Must(template.ParseFiles("template/base_user.html", "template/cart.html"))
    tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", data)
    }else{


        tmpl:= template.Must(template.ParseFiles("template/base_user.html", "template/cart.html"))
    tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", data)
    }
}
```

Now I got it:

```
{{range .EquipmentList}}
<form action="/cart?id={{.ID}}" method="POST">
<a href="/cart?id={{.ID}}">{{.Name}}</a>
<button type="submit">
</button></form>
{{end}}
```

if iam using this code, i can use the id value with r.formValue("id") in my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many ways but one of them is `<form method="POST" action="/cart/{{.Name}}">`

Comment: ok thank you, but how can I use the variable in my controller function? for example if i wanted to save it in /cart.

Comment: i tried it your way, but it show me /cart/Equipment and not /cart/name of choosen equipment

Comment: I also can imagine to pass the id of a clicked submit button, but i dont know how to save or use it in my controller.

Comment: iam using net/http

Comment: Edit my Post, got the Solution

Comment: glad could help